# Git Svn Clone initializes repo, but git repo is empty

Tags: git, version-control, migration, tortoisesvn

So I've been trying to migrate my company's CVS and SVN repositories over to Git for our modern systems. So I've created the authors file with the format:
`last_fi = FirstInitial LastName <firstinitial.lastname@company.com>`
From there, I should be able to run this command:

`git svn clone -s --authors-file=authors.txt "https://company.svnrepo.path/repoparent/repo" gitreponame --prefix=svn/`

When this is done, however, I get this:

`Initialized empty Git repository in c:/checkout/git/Suite/.git/
Using higher level of URL: https://company.svnrepo.path/repoparent/repo => https://company.svnrepo.path/repoparent
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: REPORT request failed on '/svnfolder/middir/!svn/bc/100': File not found: revision 100, path '/repoparent'
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.
This may take a while on large repositories
C:\checkout\git> 3048`

It checks r100 through the current revision (r3048) and initializes the git repo, but there's no master, no HEAD and no commits to make. I have no working directory beyond the initial git init folders and files.

I've been trying all kinds of odd and strange things just to move forward and I'm completely stumped. I think I've been looking at it too long and I'm missing something basic. But if anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So a lot of collaboration and some luck went into finding a solution for this problem. As it turns out, the path to the remote SVN server is case sensitive whereas most of the other aspects of the command are not. When I was typing repoparent, it should have been RepoParent. This seems like a stupid mistake, but I hope it can help someone else out there!

Comment: If there's a hole I'll fall into it - thanks for helping me out of this one